# how to pass an valuable with redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

I am having trouble trying to pass an valuable after the user fail the authorization. I would like to pass $error to the welcome controller but not sure how. Please help. Thank you.

```
  private function _user_check()
            {
                 //after form validation, I pass username and password to the model
                    $this->load->model('user_query');
                    $result=$this->user_query->query($this->input->post('username'),$this->
                    input->post('password'));

                    if($result)
                {
                    redirect('main');

                }else{
                    // I am not sure how to pass this error message to my welcome controller
                    $data['error']='Please check your username or password';
                    redirect('welcome');
                }


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the redirect function, you aren't providing a full URL, so CI is going to treat the parameter as an URI segments to the controller.

Knowing this, you could have something like:

```
redirect('welcome/error/error_user_pass');
```

and have your "error_user_pass" that is being passed reference error constants defined in your CI project.

Maybe something like this in your application/config/constants.php file:

```
define('error_user_pass', 'incorrect user or password, please check yo self!');
```

Then in your 'welcome' controller having something like this:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  public function error(){
    $errors = func_get_args();
    foreach( $errors as $error ){
      //echo error, or save it, or whatev
    }
  }
}
```